# Decressing frames in KineticJS ANimation Sprite

Tags: jquery, animation, kineticjs, sprite

I have  strange `issue with my animation` - when 
I shoot the enemy It should explode. And the animation is beeing done properly just one time.
Each next one has less frames. I have no idea why. Could someone help ?

Thanks in advance

I set the framespeed on 1 to make problem more visible.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/pza6eeos/
```

Comment: Can you make working jsfiddle?

Comment: hm, it works at my place. I also deleted cookies  and still have images.
http://jsfiddle.net/pza6eeos/